# Graphics card not displayed in Skyrim game graphics cards list?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, intel-graphics

I own a HP ProBook 4740s laptop, with core i7 processor and AMD Radeon HD 7650m, but when I turn on Skyrim, intel hd graphics 4000 is the only card that's shown in the graphics options.

Any idea why is this? My AMD Radeon drivers appear to be installed, when I view the device manager.

My AMD Catalyst control center also only shows intel

Update : I have reinstalled my Windows and downloaded drivers from AMD, still no luck.

Comment: It's because you bought a laptop that has switchable graphics.

Comment: What does switchable graphics mean?

Comment: It means it uses the Intel graphics until there is a need to use the Radeon graphics.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/445018/how-can-i-use-my-built-in-amd-radeon-7670m-instead-of-intel-hd-4000-graphics?rq=1

Comment: So this means that my laptop is using AMD graphics while playing?

Comment: Hard to say.  Sometimes the problem is that the setup program isn't enough load to make it flip over to the AMD card, so you can't pick it in the setup program.  It's dumb, and why auto-switching graphics sucks sometimes. ;)  Often your BIOS or CCC will allow you to force it to use one or the other.  Perhaps look into that if you haven't already.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/373419/how-can-i-use-my-built-in-ati-radeon-instead-of-intel-hd-graphics-for-opengl?rq=1

Comment: It's strange that my catalyst doesn't even show AMD card under "configure switchable graphics", only intel

Comment: Yeah that is kind of weird, have you checked the system's BIOS to ensure it's not disabled there?

Comment: I will, I'll be back in a min.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?  I already know the answer because of an existing question that is a duplicate of this question ( no idea if it has an answer ) I just remember what that user was using.

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, my BIOS only shows an option in System Configuration > Device Configuration > Switchable graphics and that's turned ON.

Comment: I just found this comment on youtube:
InsanityXI 1 month ago
Its the game being stupid dont worry :) The games will never "detect" the AMD card because its kinda hidden in the pc, but when you set to high performance, it does use it.

Answer (score 0):

In AMD Switchable graphics, the sound card won't be displayed in the settings menu. The amd graphics is only activated when one selects "high performance" for an application (such as Skyrim) in the AMD Catalyst Center.